# Update progress value from fileImporter modifier in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, progress-bar

I have a progress bar with its value updated while processing a file using the fileImporter modifier. I am not sure why the progress bar is not updated as the file is being processed (is it because it is part of the closure?). Below is how I am implementing the progress bar. Any help is greatly appreciated!

the ContentView basically has a button that triggers the processing of the selected file using a button and the .fileImporter modifier in a closure.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@ObservedObject var progress = ProgressItem()
@State var importData: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {importData = true}, label: {Text("Import Data")})
            .fileImporter(isPresented: $importData, allowedContentTypes: [UTType.plainText], allowsMultipleSelection: false) { result in
                do {
                    guard let selectedFile: URL = try result.get().first else { return }
                    let secured = selectedFile.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                    
                    DataManager().importData(fileURL: selectedFile)
                    if secured {selectedFile.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()}
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        ProgressBar(value: $progress.progress).frame(height: 20)
    }
}
```

}

The ProgressBar is a simple view that takes the progress value and updates it

```
struct ProgressBar: View {
@Binding var value: Double

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Rectangle().frame(width: geometry.size.width , height: geometry.size.height)
                .opacity(0.3)
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemTeal))
            
            Rectangle().frame(width: min(CGFloat(self.value)*geometry.size.width, geometry.size.width), height: geometry.size.height)
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
                .animation(.linear)
            Text("\(value)")
        }.cornerRadius(45.0)
    }
}
```

}

I have a ProgressItem class which is an ObservableObject that contains the progress value:

```
class ProgressItem: ObservableObject {
    @Published var progress: Double = 0
    @Published var message: String = ""
}
```

The file is processed as part of the DataManager class. For the sake of this question, I have stripped out the processing details and just have a print statement to print out each line.Below is the DataManager class that updates the ProgressValue

```
class DataManager {
    @Published var progressBar: ProgressItem? = nil
    
    init() {
        progressBar = ProgressItem()
    }
    
    func importData(fileURL: URL, delimeter: String = ",") {
        let lines = try! String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8).components(separatedBy: .newlines).filter({!$0.isEmpty})
        let numlines = lines.count
        for index in 0..<numlines {
            let line = String(lines[index])
            print("\(line)")
            progressBar?.progress = Double(index)/Double(numlines) * 100
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd inject progress item in `DataManager` via constructor

```
class DataManager {
    private var progressBar: ProgressItem? = nil
    
    init(progressBar: ProgressItem? = nil) {
        self.progressBar = progressBar
    }

    func importData(fileURL: URL, delimeter: String = ",") {

        // ... other code

        // if importing on background queue
        //DispatchQueue.main.async { // this better update async on main queue
            progressBar?.progress = Double(index)/Double(numlines) * 100
        //}
    }
```

and then inject observed item from view into `DataManager`, like

```
    // ... other code

    DataManager(progressBar: self.progress).importData(fileURL: selectedFile)

    // ... other code
```

of course somewhere/somewhen you need to reset your current progress item. I don't see any completion in your code, but if you have one it might be inside it.

Comment: thanks for your reply! When I tried to implement it the update is waiting until after reading the file to update the progress bar. Essentially, the DispatchQueue.main.async code block is waiting until the reading is finished and is updating after the fact. Any suggestions why?

Comment: Probably you do everything on main queue, try to remove it, but if it so then your UI will not be updated with progress, because import itself blocks UI.

Comment: Yes, everything was on the main queue. But then I changed the file processing to DispatchQueue.global().async. Making this change updated the progressBar but did not trigger the update of the UI once it was done.

Comment: thank you!. I got it to work. I had to put the ui update in another main.async queue.