# Updating a Progress Value in SwithUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swift5

I am trying to update a progress bar using the DispatchQueue.main.async (based on @Asperi's reply at but this does not work! [Update progress value from fileImporter modifier in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64375478/update-progress-value-from-fileimporter-modifier-in-swiftui)). The problem I am having is the progress updates waits until end of the task and then updates the progress bar which is not the expected behavior.

I put the file processing code within DispatchQueue.global().async, which executes the code right away and updates the Progress bar immediately (goes to 100% instantly) but the file processing task is still not complete. How do I get this to work the right way. Below is the code I am executing. Appreciate your help

Below is the ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var progress = ProgressItem()
    @State var importData: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {importData = true}, label: {Text("Import Data")})
                .fileImporter(isPresented: $importData, allowedContentTypes: [UTType.plainText], allowsMultipleSelection: false) { result in
                    do {
                        guard let selectedFile: URL = try result.get().first else { return }
                        let secured = selectedFile.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
                        DispatchQueue.global().async { // added this to import file asynchronously
                            DataManager(progressBar: progress).importData(fileURL: selectedFile)
                        }
                        if secured {selectedFile.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()}
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            ProgressBar(value: $progress.progress, message: $progress.message).frame(height: 20)
        }
    }
}
```

ProgressBar View:

```
struct ProgressBar: View {
    @Binding var value: Double
    @Binding var message: String
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Rectangle().frame(width: geometry.size.width , height: geometry.size.height)
                    .opacity(0.3)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemTeal))
                
                Rectangle().frame(width: min(CGFloat(self.value)*geometry.size.width, geometry.size.width), height: geometry.size.height)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
                    .animation(.linear)
                //Text("\(self.value)")
            }.cornerRadius(45.0)
        }
    }
}
```

DataManager that processes the file. Right now I have a thread.sleep(0..001) to simulate reading of the file

```
class DataManager {
    @Published var progressBar: ProgressItem? = nil
    
    init(progressBar: ProgressItem? = nil) {
        self.progressBar = progressBar
    }
    
    func importData(fileURL: URL, delimeter: String = ",") {
        let lines = try! String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8).components(separatedBy: .newlines).filter({!$0.isEmpty})
        let numlines = lines.count
        for index in 0..<numlines {
            let line = String(lines[index])
            Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.001)
            print("\(line)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async { // updating the progress value here
                self.progressBar?.progress = Double(index)/Double(numlines) * 100
                self.progressBar?.message = line
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ProgressItem:

```
class ProgressItem: ObservableObject {
    @Published var progress: Double = 0
    @Published var message: String = ""
}
```

Comment: `thread.sleep` will block the main thread.  The async dispatch won't execute until `importData` relinquishes the main thread.  You could use a `Timer` to simulate the transfer, updating the progress each time the timer "ticks".  That way you won't block any threads.

Comment: @Paulw11. Thanks for the catch. I did not realize that. I got it to work. I also had to put the UI update back into main.async queue